# Time complexity of google's re2 for a given length of regex pattern

Tags: regex, re2

I was looking into the google's `re2` implementation, I want to do the regex match using regex given by some untrusted source. I have gone through the following resources -

- [Google re2 Github](https://github.com/google/re2)
- [regex matching in the wild](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html)

With PCRE, we can get into some really bad cases and it can take exponential time to match. e.g. for regex `(.*)+b` and string like `aaaaaaaaa...` it can take `O(c^n)` time where `n` is length of string.
Some more DOS expressions documented [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS).

I understand that the `re2` will do the match in linear time for a given regex expression against a given length of a string. Now, my question is if I am able to compile a regex in `re2`, and I am putting a restriction on the length of a regex pattern then am I guaranteed that it won't run into some DOS cases mentioned in the above link or for some other regex pattern?

Comment: Per specification you won't (unless you use the length of the test string as a DOS parameter).

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to be doubly sure. No, the length of test string and length of regex pattern both will be capped. So I guess the answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re2` has **O(n) worst-case complexity** for a given string of length `n`, unlike some others regex implementations that support backtracking/look aheads.

So as long as both the length of string and length of regex pattern are capped, and you are validating the regex patterns beforehand, the `re2` cannot be DOSed.

But while migrating some patterns from PCRE or otherwise using it, you need to make sure that the regex pattern can be compiled as the implementation doesn't support many PCRE functionalities like backreferences.